# Put Pattern Into Template in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a template image that looks like this [http://imgur.com/a/q4vaz](https://imgur.com/a/q4vaz)
I need to create that template in Illustrator and put a pattern inside the squares. Can anyone point me in the right direction so I could learn how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Drawing rectangles and applying fills and strokes to objects are rudimentary functions of Adobe Illustrator. Have you tried some basic online tutorials covering how the application works?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the **Pen** / **Line** and you could set a stroke of black or what other color  you want and you would have to make lines that are the detention that you need and then connect them depending on what you are doing.

Or you can do what I said ^ and just out line the stroke of the other box.

The best way to do this is to have no fill then you can add the texture in after you finish with the outline.

Answer (score 0):

I would join all the squares into a single shape in a separate layer and apply the pattern to that.

1. Make a new layer over the one with the guidelines you have.
2. Draw all the squares over the drawing. Make sure they touch edges.
3. Go to pathfinder and use the top left option with two filled squares overlapping. It will make all your squares into one shape.
4. Add the pattern to that shape either using the sape as a clipping mask for the image with the pattern or with an illustrator pattern.
5. Make sure you drag the layer you are working on down to be underneath the guides you have so they are both visible.

This is optional but I would name both layers so there is no confusion there. 
If you save it as a pdf from illustrator it will keep the layer information. Obviously if you save as an .ai file it will also keep the layers.

Hope this helps!